# How would I get a String from another class?

Tags: java, string, user-input

```
import java.util.*;

class Player {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String number = Text.nextLine
    }
}
```

I want the user input from this class and
bring into another class and use the number variable for a 
If statement

Comment: Please provide more info.

Comment: `Text` seems to be a class and `nextLine` is a member variable, is it? if it is where did you initialize the object? or is it `Scanner` class  `nextLine()`?

Comment: Yes I'm using a scanner and yes

Comment: Take look at my answer. Is that what you ask for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the user input from this class and bring into another class and
>   use the number variable for a If statement.

It is simple take a look at below example(**make sure to add both classes in one package** different java files as **Player.java** and **ExampleClass.java**),

This is the class that `Scanner` has:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Player{
    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a number");
        //you can take input as integer if you want integer value by nextInt()
        String number = getInput.nextLine();

        ExampleClass obj = new ExampleClass(number);
        obj.checkMethod();
    }
}
```

This is the class that check number:

```
public class ExampleClass{
    int number;
    public ExampleClass(String number){
        try{
            //If you want to convert into int
            this.number = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
        }
    }

    public void checkMethod(){
        if(number > 5){
            System.out.println("Number is greater.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Number is lesser.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Few thing to mention:**

Your example code contains syntax errors, fix those first.

1. If you want integer you can use `getInput.nextInt()` rather than
   `getInput.nextLine()`.
2. You can create getter and setters to set vaues and get values. In my example I just only set value through the constructor.
3. Use proper naming convention.
4. In my example I convert the `String` into integer inside the constructor and wrap with `try`-`catch` block to prevent from `NumberFormatException`(If you input character or something you can see `wrong input` will print). Sometimes in variaus situation it is not good to use `try`-`catch` in constructor. To learn more about this, please read [Try / Catch in Constructor - Recommended Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796076/try-catch-in-constructor-recommended-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Where you normally make an import on the other class, just import the Player class and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it, I suppose you're using a scanner.
This is the way I would do that:

Scanner class:

```
public class ScannerTest { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Insert a decimal:");
            String inputValue = scanner.nextLine();
            if(!new ScannerCalc().isNumeric(inputValue)){
                System.out.println("it's not a number...");
                break;
            } 
            else
                new ScannerCalc().checkNumber(inputValue);
        }
    }
}
```

ScannerCalc class:

```
public class ScannerCalc {

    public boolean isNumeric(String s) {  
        return s != null && s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");  
    }  

    public void checkNumber(String number){

        if(Integer.parseInt(number)%2==0)
            System.out.println("it' even");
        else
            System.out.println("it's odd");

    }
}
```

Pay attention on instantiation of classes to reuse methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of a local variable in another entity, it is better to pass it as an argument to a method of the other entity. For example

```
OtherClass.operation(scanner.nextLine());   // In case method is static

new OtherClass().operation(scanner.nextLine());   // In case method is not static
```